# Replace & with &amp; in XML string in azure apim

Tags: replace, azure-api-management, ampersand, apim

I have an xml string which I am setting as body and transforming that xml into required ones.
XML String:

```
XML_STRING= "<A><B>abc</B><C>abc&ade</C></A>";
```

When

```
<set-body>@((String)context.Variables["XML_STRING"])</set-body>
<xsl-transform>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy-of select="A" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</xsl-transform>
```

I am getting the below error:

```
xsl-transform (0.398 ms)
    {
    "messages": [
        null,
        "Invalid Xml passed to transform: ' ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 1, position 2612.",
        "' ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 1, position 2612."
    ]
}
```

When I am changing "&" from xml_string to & it works fine. But I want to know that how  we can replace it using code.